# Child window closes in IE9 on click of Button

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

So I have this javascript code onclick of button for a child window which is opened from a parent window.

```
 try{  
    window.opener.item(23,Add,document.AddEdit.name.value,document.AddEdit.type.value);
 } catch(err){    
     alert('The form you are editing is not available.');
 }
```

`item` function in parent window -

```
 function item(id,action,name,type){ 
    saveScroll();
    document.abc.itemId.value = id;
    document.abc.itemAction.value = action;
    document.abc.itemName.value = name;
    document.abc.itemType.value = type;
    document.abc.submit();
 }
```

So somehow I am getting the error from `catch` block. But this happens only in IE9, it works perfectly in firefox, IE8, chrome. So the error is "**Member Not Found**". Has anyone faced this issue in IE9?

Comment: What is the actual error being caught?

Comment: Sorry, the error is "Member not found".

Comment: Isn't document.AddEdit.name going to be "AddEdit"?  I mean isn't AddEdit the name of a form?  When you name form fields and buttons, choose anything other than name, method, submit, reset...

Comment: Try to narrow down which part is causing the error by using several `console.log();` (or `alert()`) statements to see what each of `window.opener.item`, `Add`, `document.AddEdit.name.value` and `document.AddEdit.type.value` evaluate to. If it is one or both of the `document.AddEdit.xxx.value` ones causing the problem try logging/alerting just `document.AddEdit.name` and see if that works. Also, assuming `AddEdit` is an html element on your page try giving it an ID and use `document.getElementById()` instead of trying to refer to it directly.

Comment: "item" is a function from parent window. I have tried evaluating all other values and those seem to be working. Do you think "item" might be creating issue? But it seems to be working in firefox and IE8.

Comment: Could you post a url or jsfiddle showing the error? It might help us help you.

Comment: You should figure out which part is throwing the error. the call to window.opener.item, or any of it's parameters or the function itself. This is not an IE9 problem (at least not in it's current form)

Comment: @Frits - How does it work with no error in IE8 and all previous versions and other browsers too.

Comment: For some reason, jsfiddle is taking forever to load, so I am not going to bother.  However, have you tried putting X-US-Compatible in the header section to force your page into IE8 mode and try it on IE9?  If it works, then it will be an incompatibility between IE9 and IE8.  Most of such things come from new web standards (which IE9 supports and IE8 doesn't).  However, you did mention that it works on FF and Chrome, and it has to be something really exotic.

Comment: There you go: the error is "unable to get the value 'item', object is null or undefined."  So are you **ABSOLUTELY SURE** `window.opener` is valid?

Comment: I think window.opener works for child window. "item" is a function defined in parent window. I am using it in child window.

Comment: @Stephan - I tried X-US-Compatible, but it is not working still. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure since I don't have IE, but have you tried declaring 'item' like this instead:-

```
var item = function(id, action, name, type) {
//etc
}
```

The other thing I'd try is renaming 'item' to something else just in case there's some name clash...

Comment: Thank you, I changed the name of item to something else and it worked. Now I know why it was issue.